# List unique years from a set of dates in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, unique, yearmonth

I am currently achieving the process of extracting unique years from a range of dates with the use of helper columns shown here:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same using just a single formula?

Here are the three formulas I am currently using:

S column: `=UNIQUE('Earnings Input'!A2:A)`
T column: `=YEAR(S1)`
U column: `=UNIQUE(T1:T)`

Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there is no link to your spreadsheet, this is untested, but you can try this:

`=ArrayFormula(SORT(UNIQUE(YEAR(FILTER('Earnings Input'!A2:A,ISNUMBER('Earnings Input'!A2:A))))))`

`FILTER(   ,ISNUMBER( ))` filters in only values that could reasonably be a date.

`YEAR` gets the years for those entries.

`UNIQUE` reduces to the unique listing

`SORT` assures the results will be in ascending order.

Comment: I have just tested your answer and it seems to be working, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked as expected.